# If data is exits in sql then msg box data exist or else insert data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm Trying Insert data but it already exist in database then it should give msgbox that it already exist but not then insert

Answer (score 0):

Yon can use Dcount

```
If Dcount("*", "test", "ID= " & ID ) = 0 Then
    str = "INSERT INTO test(id) " & _
             " VALUES (" & id & ")
    Db.Execute str
Else
    MsgBox "Data already exists in the table."
End If
```